# Android app insert data on a table and upload a photo

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm already using Azure Mobile Services with the Android SDK to add data to a table, but now I need to upload 3 photos from the device to my storage on Azure. How can I do this?

Can I use the same script to add data to the table and upload the photos to the storage? Or should I add the azure storage sdk to my app and do these things separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the [Azure Storage SDK for Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android). The Mobile Services SDK is just for Mobile Services. You have to upload your files separately using Azure Storage SDK.

[Here is some interesting article for messing with both Mobile Services and Storage Services in Azure from Android](http://chrisrisner.com/Android-and-Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage). The article provides nice samples.